# Multiple select - value of deselect returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-select-query

### Description

I am using a jquery plugin [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) which pretty much does something like this:

[image]

This lets me add each option one by one or remove each option one by one. For every option selected, I create a new *element* with the selected option's *value* as the *id*.

### Problem

The problem is when I remove an option from the list. For example:

```
$('#multiple-select').on('change', function(e){
  alert($(e.target).val());
});
```

Will return the correct *value* if an option is added, however it returns *null* if we remove an option. I need to be able to get the value of the option being deselected so I can remove it in the other *element*.

### Question

How can I get the deselected option's value to return the actual value instead of null? Or is there another way to bypass this problem?

All I need to be able to do is find the option being deselected and removing it from the other element (knowing that the element's id is built on the option's value).

### Update

Remove code as requested:

```
$('body').on('change', benefs, function(e){
  var $nbparts = $(participantNbParts),
      $target = $(e.target),
      $val = $target.val(),
      $name = $target.text();

      if($val == null){
        //this is because we deleted something thus we need to remove it from $nbparts which is a pitty since we don't know what it was before it got deleted
      }else{
        //someone was added
        $(create_row_expense_nb_parts_participant($name, $val)).appendTo($nbparts).show('slow');
        $nbparts.parent().show('fast');
      }
});
```

Comment: The removal code is irrelevant, since all it comes down to is getting value of a deselected option.

Comment: why `$('body').on('change' , .....)` ? why you targeting body element ?

Comment: @Sachink, this is because live() in jquery was deprecated, so if any new elements are added in my select (which is the case) the on change event will be applied to them. In the end I am targeting the select... "benefs" is the multiple select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) provides `selected` and `deselected` using which you can identify selected and deselected values respectively, like:

```
$("#your_element_id").on('change', function (evt, params) {

    var selected = params.selected;
    var removed = params.deselected; //gives you the deselected value

    //assuming your option ids are numbers
    if( removed > 0 ) {
        console.log( "Value removed is:" + removed );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

From its [documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) in the `change` event description you have

> Chosen triggers the standard DOM event whenever a selection is made
>   (it also sends a selected or deselected parameter that tells you which
>   option was changed).

This suggests you should observe the arguments received by the event handler at run time to get a hint about (and most likely a reference to) the removed/deselected option.